# Computing approximations of exponential

Tags: functions, evaluation

I have the code

```
f[x_] := 13 x e^-x
bit = Nest[f, 1, #] & /@ Prepend[1]@Range[4, 16, 4]
```

Which I am using to compute values of $f^{(4)}(1), f^{(8)} (1), \cdots$. However, Mathematica does not give me decimal approximate values. Instead I get values in terms of $e$ which I do not want. Does anyone know to force Mathematica to give me decimal approximations? Say to the fifth or fourth digit?

Comment: I recommend that you use `N`.

Comment: That is exactly what I need! Thank you.

Comment: Also, do you mean `e` or `E`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
f[x_] := 13. x E^-x
bit = Nest[f, 1, #] & /@ Prepend[1]@Range[4, 16, 4]
(* {4.78243, 0.937064, 0.926543, 0.922671, 0.921091} *)
```

You need to use `E` not `e` in Mathematica ([documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html)), or alternatively `Exp[-x]`.

Comment: That works. I wasn't aware I had to use `E` so thank you for the information!